# mysql alias and calculations with cast

Tags: mysql

Mysql sql query:

```
SELECT product_id,
       price,
       markup, 
       CAST((price*(100+markup)DIV 100)AS DECIMAL(10,4)) AS  salesprice 
from products
```

The result i get from the above mysql is as follows:

id    price    markup  salesprice

'2', '18.4000', '20.0', '22.0000'

The sales price i get is 22.0000 instead of 22.0800. (18.4000 x 110 /100)
I have used CAST salesprice to DECIMAL (10,4)....
The Price and markup fields are DECIMAL(10,4) in DB.

What needs to be done to get **22.0800** ??

Comment: @Sadikhasan OOps! Sorry....My mistake. Thank you

Comment: Have you solved your problem? –